# Open Facebook group, but restrict user posting

Tags: facebook, facebook-groups

We have a group that we have been using to basically run a D&D game. It's a closed group, and we want to open it so that the general public can follow the progress.

However, since this is a fairly structured system that we have created, we don't want random people posting, and throwing everything into chaos.

What we want to achieve is allow only the chosen party (i.e. those participating in the story) to be able to post, and restrict everyone else from posting, even if they follow the page.
(This includes commenting as well).

Is there any possibility?

(Please let me know if you need more information)

Comment: Do you need the "players" (sorry, I don't know the appropriate term) to be able to comment, as well? Do you want non-"players" (the general public) to be able to interact with your posts in other ways (liking, sharing, saving)?

Comment: @RamonMelo yes, the players do need to comment, but we want to restrict the general public from posting or commenting

Answer (score 1):

Following are the settings you can change:

- Set that all posts must be approved by the administrator.
- Turn off commenting in the group you admin.

Once you set the approval for the posts, no one can post in the group without admin approval (note: if there are more than one admin, any admin can approve). An admin can also disable the commenting for any post or delete any comment on existing post.

For more details see the [Group Admin Basics](https://www.facebook.com/help/418065968237061/).

Comment: How does this affect commenting? Will a new user be able to comment freely on any post?

Comment: No. If you (admin) has turn off commenting for any post, no one will able to comment on that posts.