# How to allow only select few to post on Facebook Group I am Admin of?

Tags: facebook, facebook-groups

I want to allow selected people to post on Facebook Group and not all. Others can reply/comment to post, like and share etc.

Currently I see "Only Admin" or "All" setting in posting permission.

Another questions that exist here don't want to allow commenting by the general members but I want to allow reacting and commenting to the post created by selected members ( allowed to post). Also, answer is not available there.

Comment: I could regulate posts but then I need to involve myself a lot. Also, I like to respect few members who post quality posts. So, if I regulate all posts then their posts will also come into queue to clear by Admin, which I don't want.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Open Facebook group, but restrict user posting](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/102653/open-facebook-group-but-restrict-user-posting)

Answer (score 2):

From [this thread](https://www.facebook.com/help/community/question/?id=745485873847) on Facebook support page:

> When you have post approval turned on, there is an option when somebody posts to always allow them to post (with out approval). Note once you give them that approval the only way to take it away is to remove them from group and then they have to request to come back.

Diving a bit deeper, however, I found this caveat:

> you cant get the option in in your mobile facebook app. I used a web browser to get the option. Once you approved the post, The following comes automatically.
>
> `This post was approved and published to the group. View the post. Automatically approve posts by Mr Xy.`

So, apparently, it's an option only available through the desktop web interface.

Comment: This is not the answer which answers my question but it look like this only way available right now. In my solution, at start or later I could tell if this member can post or not! Once not allowed he know that he cannot post.

Comment: @SatyaPrakash I did think the same when I was writing it, but Facebook does not allow for much micromanagement. I believe the solution you want, if it exists at all, will not be straightforward: it will require many workarounds that might be a hassle to maintain.

Comment: No, I could have said at start when approving members. I want to see a box at start that tells this member allowed to post or not. 
Actually I want to deny all members post new post but comment/like etc. So, default is not allowed. But at the time of accepting new members, I could have taken few as post-able members. Only few members could have been allowed to post. So, it is pretty straight forward.